# What is the effect of the filter size in a CNN

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, feature-engineering

I am new in deep learning and I try to understand some details about CNN. Could you explain to me what is the effect of the filter size e.g 5*5 vs 7*7  on features extraction and locality structure ?

Answer (score 1):

If you work in natural language processing, you can view the filter size in a CNN as the n-gram size.

If you work in computer vision, you can view the filter size in a CNN as the receptive field.

See [How to work multiple filter region sizes: 2, 3 and 4 in CNN?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/234692/12359) to get a better intuition.

> how to fix the size of the filter.

The choice of the size of the filter depends on the dataset. I am not aware of any rule of thumb, typically one would start with a size of the filter that has been used in similar works. Some ideas: [What are the state-of-the-art methods to determine parameters in CNN, NN, RNN, or any deep learning models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/239020/12359) . E.g. in {1} we used Gaussian Processes to automatically choose the filter height.

---

References:

- {1} Franck Dernoncourt, Ji Young Lee. [Optimizing Neural Network Hyperparameters with Gaussian Processes for Dialog Act Classification](http://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08703), IEEE SLT 2016.

Comment: I mean how to fix the size of the filter. What is the effect on extracting features when we use a small filter size vs big filter size ?

Comment: @BetterEnglish added in answer.